# How to remove libraries from the G++ Linker command in CodeLite? Can't find them

Tags: linux, linker, g++, wxwidgets, codelite

I'm trying to compile my wxWidgets app but it won't let me because it can't find these libraries. I searched for these libraries and they indeed, are not on my computer, so how can I get rid of them from the linker? Don't see the libraries in the Active Project Settings anywhere and not sure where these libraries are getting specified (I looked all over the "linker" settings and then some). Kind of annoying

```
/usr/bin/make -j2 -e -f  Makefile
----------Building project:[ LearnFrench - Debug ]----------
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/oem/Documents/CodeliteProjects/LearnFrench'
/usr/bin/g++ -o ../../Documents/build-Debug/bin/LearnFrench @../../Documents/build-Debug/__/CodeliteProjects/LearnFrench/ObjectsList.txt -L/usr/lib/codelite -L/usr/local/lib/  -l wx_gtk3u_stc-3.2.so.0 -l wx_gtk3u_html-3.2 -l wx_gtk3u_aui-3.2.so.0 -l wx_gtk3u_adv-3.2 -l wx_gtk3u_stc-3.2.so.0.2.1 -l wx_gtk3u_propgrid-3.2.so.0.2.1 -l wx_gtk3u_gl-3.2 -l wx_gtk3u_html-3.2.so.0 -l wx_gtk3u_adv-3.2.so.0 -l wx_gtk3u_aui-3.2.so.0.2.1 -l wx_gtk3u_core-3.2.so.0.2.1 -l wx_gtk3u_gl-3.2.so.0 -l wx_baseu_net-3.2.so.0 -l wx_gtk3u_xrc-3.2.so.0 -l wx_gtk3u_ribbon-3.2 -l wx_gtk3u_richtext-3.2.so.0.2.1 -l wx_gtk3u_core-3.2 -l wx_gtk3u_core-3.2.so.0 -l wx_gtk3u_propgrid-3.2 -l wx_gtk3u_qa-3.2 -l wx_gtk3u_qa-3.2.so.0 -l wx_gtk3u_qa-3.2.so.0.2.1 -l wx_gtk3u_xrc-3.2 -l wx_gtk3u_propgrid-3.2.so.0 -l wx_baseu-3.2.so.0.2.1 -l wx_gtk3u_gl-3.2.so.0.2.1 -l wx_gtk3u_richtext-3.2 -l wx_gtk3u_adv-3.2.so.0.2.1 -l wx_baseu_xml-3.2.so.0.2.1 -l wx_gtk3u_xrc-3.2.so.0.2.1 -l wx_baseu_xml-3.2 -l wx_baseu-3.2.so.0 -l wx_gtk3u_ribbon-3.2.so.0.2.1 -l wx_baseu_net-3.2 -l wx_gtk3u_html-3.2.so.0.2.1 -l wx_baseu-3.2 -l wx_gtk3u_aui-3.2 -l wx_baseu_net-3.2.so.0.2.1 -l wx_gtk3u_richtext-3.2.so.0 -l wx_gtk3u_stc-3.2 -l wx_baseu_xml-3.2.so.0 -l wx_gtk3u_ribbon-3.2.so.0
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lwx_gtk3u_stc-3.2.so.0: No such file or directory
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lwx_gtk3u_aui-3.2.so.0: No such file or directory
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lwx_gtk3u_stc-3.2.so.0.2.1: No such file or directory
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lwx_gtk3u_propgrid-3.2.so.0.2.1: No such file or directory
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lwx_gtk3u_html-3.2.so.0: No such file or directory
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lwx_gtk3u_adv-3.2.so.0: No such file or directory
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lwx_gtk3u_aui-3.2.so.0.2.1: No such file or directory
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lwx_gtk3u_core-3.2.so.0.2.1: No such file or directory
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lwx_gtk3u_gl-3.2.so.0: No such file or directory
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lwx_baseu_net-3.2.so.0: No such file or directory
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lwx_gtk3u_xrc-3.2.so.0: No such file or directory
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lwx_gtk3u_richtext-3.2.so.0.2.1: No such file or directory
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lwx_gtk3u_core-3.2.so.0: No such file or directory
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lwx_gtk3u_qa-3.2.so.0: No such file or directory
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lwx_gtk3u_qa-3.2.so.0.2.1: No such file or directory
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lwx_gtk3u_propgrid-3.2.so.0: No such file or directory
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lwx_baseu-3.2.so.0.2.1: No such file or directory
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lwx_gtk3u_gl-3.2.so.0.2.1: No such file or directory
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lwx_gtk3u_adv-3.2.so.0.2.1: No such file or directory
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lwx_baseu_xml-3.2.so.0.2.1: No such file or directory
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lwx_gtk3u_xrc-3.2.so.0.2.1: No such file or directory
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lwx_baseu-3.2.so.0: No such file or directory
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lwx_gtk3u_ribbon-3.2.so.0.2.1: No such file or directory
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lwx_gtk3u_html-3.2.so.0.2.1: No such file or directory
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lwx_baseu_net-3.2.so.0.2.1: No such file or directory
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lwx_gtk3u_richtext-3.2.so.0: No such file or directory
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lwx_baseu_xml-3.2.so.0: No such file or directory
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lwx_gtk3u_ribbon-3.2.so.0: No such file or directory
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[1]: *** [LearnFrench.mk:82: ../../Documents/build-Debug/bin/LearnFrench] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/oem/Documents/CodeliteProjects/LearnFrench'
make: *** [Makefile:5: All] Error 2
=== build completed successfully (0 errors, 0 warnings) ===
```

I was expecting to find the libraries in the project settings but can't find them anywhere.

Comment: It seems very strange that you're linking with `so.0` and `so.0.2.1` libraries. Where do these libraries names come from? You should be using `wx-config --libs` output.

Answer (score 0):

Think the library names must've been renamed in the newest source code when I recompiled and installed them from source, from something.so to libsomething.so.

So I created softlinks in the lib folder between the real libraries and the ones it couldn't find because they weren't there (With their original names), and it worked. The terminal lines looked like this:

```
    sudo ln -s libwx_baseu-3.2.so.0.2.1 wx_baseu-3.2.so.0.2.1

    sudo ln -s libwx_baseu-3.2.so.0.2.1 wx_baseu-3.2.so.0

    sudo ln -s libwx_baseu-3.2.so.0.2.1 wx_baseu-3.2
```

Now my code is compiling and running like normal.

Comment: This is definitely wrong, there is absolutely no way you should be using without `lib` prefix. You just hid the real problem and you will run into trouble due to it later.